# How to merge an array with its array elements in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, merge

I have an array like below;

```
constants = ['(1,2)', '(1,5,1)', '1']
```

I would like to transform the array into like below;

```
constants = [(1,2), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

For doing this, i tried some operations;

```
from ast import literal_eval
import numpy as np
constants = literal_eval(str(constants).replace("'",""))
constants = [(np.arange(*i) if len(i)==3 else i) if isinstance(i, tuple) else i for i in constants]
```

And the output was;

```
constants = [(1, 2), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 1]
```

So, this is not expected result and I'm stuck in this step. The question is, how can i merge the array with its parent array?

Comment: why isn't the first tuple converted?

Comment: I don't need convert it. I need to convert tuples has 3 values.

Comment: Doesn't `np.arange(1,5,1)` return `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])`?

Comment: @taras Yes it does. But it's not my problem. The problem is how to merge it with parent array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
from ast import literal_eval

constants = ['(1,2)', '(1,5,1)', '1']
res = []
for i in constants:                
    val = literal_eval(i)              #Convert to python object
    if isinstance(val, tuple):         #Check if element is tuple
        if len(val) == 3:              #Check if no of elements in tuple == 3
            val = list(val)
            val[1]+=1
            res.extend(range(*val))
            continue            
    res.append(val)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 2), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Comment: what if the array: `constants = ['(1,2)', '(1,5,1)', '1', '(0.1, 0.9, 0.1)']` ? The error is: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: What is the expected output of `['(1,2)', '(1,5,1)', '1', '(0.1, 0.9, 0.1)']` ?

Comment: The expected result: `[(1,2), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]`

Comment: I solved it; just change the `range(*val)` to `np.arange(*val)`.

Comment: Yes...I was about to post that :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use code below to resolve parsing described above:

```
from ast import literal_eval


constants = ['(1,2)', '(1,5,1)', '1']
processed = []

for index, c in enumerate(constants):
    parsed = literal_eval(c)
    if isinstance(parsed, (tuple, list)) and index != 0:
        processed.extend(range(1, max(parsed) + 1))
    else:
        processed.append(parsed)

print processed  # [(1, 2), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Comment: TypeError: isinstance expected 2 arguments, got 3

Comment: The result is not i wanted. The result should be; [(1,2), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko, what if a tuple is not the first element of the list?

Comment: @taras item will be appended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this question is very literal, and that you always want to transform this:

```
constants = ['(a, b)', '(x, y, z)', 'i']
```

into this:

```
transformed = [(a,b), x, x+z, x+2*z, ..., y, i]
```

such that the second tuple is a range from `x` to `y` with step `z`. So your final transformed array is the first element, then the range defined by your second element, and then your last element. The easiest way to do this is simply step-by-step:

```
constants = ['(a, b)', '(x, y, z)', 'i']
literals = [eval(k) for k in constants]    # get rid of the strings
part1 = [literals[0]]                      # individually make each of the three parts of your list
part2 = [k for k in range(literals[1][0], literals[1][1] + 1, literals[1][2])]    # or if you don't need to include y then you could just do range(literals[1])
part3 = [literals[2]]
transformed = part1 + part2 + part3
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following:

```
res = []
for cst in constants:

    if isinstance(cst,tuple) and (len(cst) == 3):
        #add the range to the list
        res.extend(range(cst[0],cst[1], cst[2]))
    else:
        res.append(cst)
```

res has the result you want. 
There may be a more elegant way to solve it.